# C# smart device add Horizontal scrollbar to listBox

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

can i add horizontal scrollbar to `ListBox` in C# smart device ???

can't find any settings.

please help me ...

Comment: Check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12872/Horizontal-scroll-bar-in-a-combo-box-or-a-listbox

Answer (score 2):

try

```
listBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
```

Comment: In C# for smart devices there is not such think